# How to crawl other websites with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, search, solr, web-crawler

I am actually looking for a solution to crawl specified websites with Drupal and make theres content visibil in my search after the crawling process.
Any ideas about that?

I tried for now the Drupal Apache Solr Modul which is working very good as a search as it should be, but i dont know how to extend it, so that the index is filled with content of other sites?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Feeds Crawler Module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_crawler)